# Add default behaviour to all public methods

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible in C# to implement a mechanism that will automatically add the default behaviour to each public method of given classes (which implement given interface or have given attribute .. or whatever)?

For example, I have a method:

```
    public void DoSomething(MyClass a) {
       if (a != null) {
          // Do method body
       }
       else{
          // Throw exception (a argument of type MyClass is null)
       }
    }
```

I would like to have this condition automatically added for each attribute without the need for writing it every time for given public methods.

Is there anything (any kind of mechanism) I could use for something like that?

Comment: You are looking for [Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx).

Comment: Don't forget to fail fast http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf

Comment: There is a tool Postsharp will help you to do this https://www.postsharp.net/

Comment: You can wrap your method body as an Action or Func inside another method that takes your Action/Func as a parameter.

Comment: I edited my answer with another trick that uses operator overloading. The downside is that you have to change your method signature

Answer (score 2):

To avoid reflection, you can use a generic method:

```
public void DoSomething(MyClass a) => MakeSomeStaff(a, () => { /* Do method body */ });


private void MakeSomeStaff<T>(T item, Action action) where T: class
{
    if (item == null)
        throw new Exception();

    action();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Had an idea that abuses operator overloading, original answer at the bottom:**
Use operator overloading to throw on null

```
public struct Some<T> where T : class {
    public T Value { get; }

    public Some(T value)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(value, null))
            throw new Exception();
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString() => Value.ToString();
    public static implicit operator T(Some<T> some) => some.Value;
    public static implicit operator Some<T>(T value) => new Some<T>(value);    
}

private void DoThingsInternal(string foo) =>       
    Console.Out.WriteLine($"string len:{foo.Length}"); 

public void DoStuff(Some<string> foo) 
{
    DoThingsInternal(foo);
    string fooStr = foo;
    string fooStrBis = foo.Value;
    // do stuff 
}
```

**Original answer**
You can use an extension method to throw for you

```
public static class NotNullExt{
    public static T Ensure<T>(this T value,string message=null) where T:class
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(null,value) throw new Exception(message??"Null value");
        return value;
    }
}
public void DoSomething(MyClass a) {
    a=a.Ensure("foo");
    // go ...
}
```